# Map values based on ID within Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to map specific values to a column if the column contains a specific value.

**Data**

```
ID TYPE STAT
aa a1   y
aa a2   n
aa a3   y
bb a1   y
bb a1   n
bb b2   n
```

**Desired**

```
ID TYPE STAT RANGE
aa a1   y    20
aa a2   n    10
aa a3   y    5
bb a1   y    20
bb a1   n    20
bb b2   n    10
```

**Doing**

```
data = {
        a1:20,
        a2:10,
        a3:5,
        b2:10
      }
output = df.merge(data.rename(columns={"TYPE": "RANGE"}), how="left"))
```

Creating a dict and mapping/appending:

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `df['RANGE'] = df['TYPE'].map(data)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def find_num(row):
    if row in data:
        return data[row]
    else:
        return np.NaN

df['RANGE'] = df['TYPE'].apply(find_num)

print(df)
```